# ListView doesn't fire changed event on selectedItemProperty

Tags: listview, javafx-2

I've created a ListView with a bunch of Strings, it has Multiple Selection mode and finally I added a Listener to the selectedItemProperty() just as the following:

```
  ObservableList<String> myStringsObsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(strings);
  ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>(myStringsObsList);
  listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

  listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val) 
       {
         System.out.println("Selection Changed!");
       }
     }
  });
```

Everything is printed OK when selecting items, but once I start to deselect items using Ctrl. Nothing is printed here as the changed event is probably not fired.

Anyone knows if this is a bug? or Im doing something wrong here?

At the end I only need to know if the selection changed somehow (whether selecting or deselecting items), so I can launch another process.

EDIT---
When deselecting with Ctrl, "Selection Changed!" is printed only when the last item of the selected items is deselected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register this listener instead to the listview:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
        .addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("Selection Changed!");

            }

        });
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution works perfectly well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as above but add line to capture the indices.

```
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
    .addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("Selection Changed!");
            ObservableList<Integer> sel = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
        }

    });
```